# SearchKick : How to search fields with regex in elastic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, elasticsearch, searchkick

I want to search articles based on title which is case insensitive.

I tried to code like this

> `Article.search(where: {title: /some_titles_here/i}, load: false)`

But this is not working.

Comment: I have tried Article.search(where: {title: {regexp: /some_title_here/i}}, load: false)

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to enable field search for case insensitive fields, you need to create the appropriate mapping on the field an index creation time , here is an example on how to do that:

```
$ curl -XPUT localhost:9200/Article/ -d '
{
  "settings":{
     "index":{
        "analysis":{
           "analyzer":{
              "analyzer_keyword":{
                 "tokenizer":"keyword",
                 "filter":"lowercase"
              }
           }
        }
     }
  },
  "mappings":{
     "Article":{
        "properties":{
           "title":{
              "analyzer":"analyzer_keyword",
              "type":"string"
           }
        }
     }
  }
}'
```

There is also an option to specify the analyzer at search time , but that depends on the ES version you use and it can be less performant than using an analyzer at index creation time.